# Does HDMI 2.0 support 5120x1440 at 70hz?

Tags: display, hdmi, 4k-resolution

Does anybody know if HDMI 2.0 supports 5120x1440 at 70hz?

I know the maximum for HDMI 2.0 is 4k at 60hz, but seeing as 5120x1440 has 88% of the pixels of 4k, is 70hz supported at this resolution?

I am specifically asking about the HDMI 2.0 port in the 14" M1 Macbook Pro.

Comment: I'd have to say "definitely maybe". True 4K is 3840 x 2160 for 8,294,400 pixels. The resolution asked is 5120 x 1440 at 7,372,800 pixels per frame. HDMI 2.0 has a high enough data rate for what you want, your resolution is around 10.6Gbit/s (5120 x 1440 x 24 x 60 = 10616832000) and HDMI 2.0 *should* do 14.4Gbit/s.

Comment: Thanks @Mokubai, will find out in a week or so and update this question!

Comment: With HDR? 4:4:4 chroma subsampling?

Comment: From comments below, you're asking about a new M1 MacBook Pro. Macs don't do higher than 60Hz [fixed refresh rate]. Apple don't seem to have any interest in it. ProMotion is capable of 120Hz, but not under your control. https://support.apple.com/HT210742

Comment: @Tetsujin I can output at 5120x1440@70hz no problem on my current M1 Air with a usb-c HDMI dongle, was hoping the HDMI port on the new Pro would negate the need for the dongle.

Comment: 60Hz has been Apple's refresh rate for 2 decades, not a 70 to be seen, so idk how you managed it. They publish spec on every single machine, right back. That should be the first place to look - https://support.apple.com/kb/SP854

Comment: @JMK having a play with https://tomverbeure.github.io/video_timings_calculator it looks like 4K60 definitely does use more bandwidth than your resolution at 90% of HDMI 2.0 bandwidth while your resolution in the same CVT-RB mode is around 80% of the link bandwidth. The old "plain" CVT mode is only really relevant for analogue displays that require time to for overscan and to come back to the start of a line. As long as your display and resolution is correctly detected I think it *should* work.

Comment: What's your motivation for trying to squeeze an odd refresh rate out of a display anyway?

Comment: It's the recommended refresh rate for this display @Tetsujin https://www.amazon.co.uk/Philips-498P9-ultrawide-Ergonomic-MultiView/dp/B08DP5G1LL

Comment: Well, it's the maximum. I'm not really sure what it would gain you in real terms. Just use 60. It's been fine for everybody ever since we got rid of flickery CRT screens [which were, admittedly, damned irritating at 60;) Gamers have a penchant for high refresh rates, but I'm still almost certain it's a perception issue rather than a real one. [Many don't know the difference between refresh rate & fps & tend to confuse the two very frequently.] btw, whilst I'm typing this low resource bit of text, my display is refreshing at 60Hz, my GPU at 4 fps.

Answer (score 1):

Digital interfaces such as HDMI and DisplayPort have a limit on the pixel
or data rate they can support, but you can normally trade off "resolution"
(pixel format/total pixel count) and refresh rate, so long as you stay
within the data rate limit of the given interface.

[HDMI 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_2.0)
has maximum video bandwidth of 18.0 Gbit/s. This enables it to carry
4K video at 60 Hz, 1440p at 144hz and 1080p at 240hz.

For calculating the required bandwidth,
I found the interesting article of
[How do you calculate DisplayPort / HDMI bandwidth?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monitors/comments/ayvt4r/how_do_you_calculate_displayport_hdmi_bandwidth/)

The formula advanced there was :

> ```
> (H + Hblank) × (V + Vblank) × C × F
> ```
>
> Where:
>
> - H is the horizonal pixel count
> - V is the vertical pixel count
> - C is the color depth in bits per pixel
> - F is the refresh frequency in Hz
> - Hblank and Vblank are the timing parameters, obtained from a standards document or set by the manufacturer.

Substituting our values for 5120x1440 at 70hz :

- H = 5120 px
- V = 1440 px
- C = 24 bit/px (8 bits per channel × 3 channels: R, G, and B)
- F = 60 Hz
- Hblank = 560 (obtained from CTA-861 standard)
- Vblank = 90 (obtained from CTA-861 standard)

Required data rate = (5120 + 560) × (1440 + 90) × 24 × 70
= 5680 × 1530 × 24 × 70
= 14599872000 bit/s
= 14.6 Gbit/s

This doesn't fit (or barely fits) within the often-quoted limit
of 14.4 Gbit/s. However, as Wikipedia quotes the figure of
18.0 Gbit/s, it might fit after all. A good-quality cable is
recommended.

Note 1 : The values of Hblank and Vblank above are as found in
the linked article, but may not be precise for your hardware.

Note 2 : The comments below my answer say that, in any case,
the Macbook doesn't support over 60hz.
Read the comments for more information.

Comment: Are you using the "true" 5K resolution or the vertically cut down resolution of OP? I just calculated the bit rate at somewhere north of 10.6Gbit/s while HDMI 2.0 should do 14.4 Gbit/s

Comment: Interesting thanks, my OG M1 Macbook Air can do 5120x1440@70hz fine with a USB-C to HDMI adapter so I'm not worried about that, upgrading to the 14" Pro and was wondering if it's HDMI port would support it (so I could free up a USB-C port)

Comment: @Mokubai: I'm not sure of the correct calculation, which is why I used the Bandwidth Calculator.

Comment: That bandwidth calculator did not have an option for 5120x1440, it was 5120x2160.

Comment: @Romen: My bad, you're right.

Comment: @Mokubai: I found an interesting bandwidth calculation formula on the internet and rewrote my answer.

Comment: harry - now we've discovered it's a MacBook the rules change. Apple doesn't do over 60Hz unless you enable ProMotion, which will run variable refresh up to 120Hz, but not under user control. So the answer is no… it would be yes, if the display can use ProMotion, but as far as I'm aware, there is no standalone 3rd party display that can.

Comment: @harrymc I also found https://tomverbeure.github.io/video_timings_calculator which suggested that there are "Reduced Blanking" (CVT-RB) modes which are possible to use, and are also necessary for 4K60 over HDMI 2.0 in the first place. [4K60 bandwidth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNEU7.png) vs [5120 * 1440 bandwidth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oicFp.png) It seems that the default blanking zones are surprisingly large. and 4K results in ~90% use of the 14.4Gbps available while OP should be using about 80% with their resolution. (feel free to use my images if you wish)

Comment: I think the large blanking zone you have assumes a CRT screen which would need time for the beam to be pulled back to the start of the line. From [Wikipedia: Coordinated Video Timings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Video_Timings) "CVT also specifies a mode ("CVT-R") which significantly reduces these blanking intervals (to a period insufficient for CRT displays to work correctly) in the interests of saving video signal bandwidth when modern displays such as LCD monitors are being used, since such displays typically do not require these pauses in the picture data."

Comment: @Mokubai: HDMI seems to use the CTA-861 standard whose blanking values were quoted in the link I found and in the calculation. See [random reference](https://www.cta.tech/Resources/i3-Magazine/i3-Issues/2019/November-December/cta-861-ctas-most-popular-standard) : "The ubiquitous HDMI interface relies on CTA-861". Optimizations are always possible, so these numbers are imprecise for any given hardware.

Comment: @harrymc I ended up down a rabbit hole suggesting that graphics cards can use either CVT-RB or CEA-861 with CEA-861 maybe being a "HDTV" mode in some places and I can't see 1440p modes in the vertical resolution of [EDID CEA-861 info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data#CEA-861-E) so I'm not convinced CEA-861 applies outside of "standard" resolutions like 4K, 1080p and 576i. For 1440 and other weird resolutions I *think* CVT-RB applies. My head aches so I'm going to leave it to you now, but my 4K image shows the option for CEA-861 at least.

Comment: @Mokubai: My head is in a similar state, but I think we have covered the subject well enough for now, for people that aren't video engineers.

Comment: Appreciate the effort folks :)

Comment: I can attest that even 75Hz is possible at 5120x1440 as I have a Samsung CRG90 that will operate at this over HDMI if a custom video mode is added for it.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is...no. Well, sort of.

When I plug directly into the HDMI port on the Macbook I get the following options (5120x1440 not even suggested as a resolution):

[image: Apple Display Settings, showing many other resolutions, but not 5120x1440]

BUT, when I use my USB-C to HDMI 2.0 dongle, it works fine:

[image: Apple Display Settings, showing 5120x1440@70hz successfully]

Funnily enough, the adapter I am using is a Microsoft Surface one -> https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/d/surface-usb-c-to-hdmi-adaptor/94chb2m80s54

Why the USB-C to HDMI 2.0 adapter works perfectly, but the internal HDMI 2.0 port doesn't work at all, is a complete mystery to me! If anybody knows, let me know :-)

Comment: Perhaps the adapter is HDMI 2.1?

Answer (score -3):

The max resolution for HDMI 2.0 is 4K @ 60 Hz.

It cannot do 5K

Comment: The resolution mentioned isn't "5K", it just happens to be 5K wide. It is 5K with about 3/4 the height of 4K. True 4K is 3840 x 2160 for 8,294,400 pixels. The resolution asked is 5120 x 1440 at 7,372,800 pixels per frame.

Comment: I knew somebody would answer with this, so I specifically covered it in my question 

Comment: Thanks All. And thanks for the down votes too. I'll wait until the more elaborately authored answers lead back to exactly what i've said 